# How can I ensure Redshift Unload Copy columns are in correct order?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to use the [UnloadCopyUtility](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/UnloadCopyUtility) to migrate an instance to an encrypted instance but some of the tables fail because it is trying to insert the values into the wrong columns. Is there are a way I can ensure the columns are mapped to the values correctly? I can adjust the python script locally if need be

Answer (score 0):

I feel, this should be possible in UnloadCopy utility as well.
But here I'm trying to answer more of generic solution withput UnloadCopy utility, so that it may be helpful to others as an alternate solution.

1. In unload command you could specify the columns like C1,C2,C3,...
2. Use same sequence columns in copy command while loading data in RedShift.

Unload command example.

```
unload ('select C1,C2,C3,... from venue') to 's3://mybucket/tickit/unload/venue_' iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole' parallel off;
```

Copy command example with specific columns sequence of above unloaded files.

```
copy table (C1,C2,C3,...) from 's3://<your-bucket-name>/load/key_prefix' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<Your-Access-Key-ID>;aws_secret_access_key=<Your-Secret-Access-Key>' options;
```